# Multiple Items From DataGridVirew Saving Problem

Tags: c#, sql

I Have a form Called PurchaseInvoiceForm. It has many products when i add multiple product in DataGridView He Never Save All Items But it shows some error.I have a DLL which i created 
to use for Data Save | Retrieve And Perform some other actions on it. Here is the following code which i used.

This is the first thing when i click SaveButton.

```
private void SaveMetroTile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsFormOk())
        {
            if (this.IsUpdate)
            {
                //Do Update Process
                SaveOrUpdateStock("usp_PurchaseInvoiceSaveOrUpdateStockDetails");
                ShowSucessMessage("Purchase Invoice Has Been Updated Successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                //Do Save Process
                SaveOrUpdateStock("usp_PurchaseInvoiceSaveOrUpdateStockDetails");
                ShowSucessMessage("Purchase Invoice Has Been Added Successfully");
            }

        }

    }
```

This is the method that is used to save or update record it accepts Stored Procedure and object.

```
    private void SaveOrUpdateStock(string storedProceName)
    {
        DbSQLServer db = new DbSQLServer(AppSetting.ConnectionString());
        db.SaveOrUpdateRecord(storedProceName, GetObject());
    }
    private StockDetails GetObject()
    {
        StockDetails stock = new StockDetails();
        try
        {     
            stock.ProcessType = (this.IsUpdate) ? (int)ProcessType.Update : (int)ProcessType.Save;
            stock.PurchaseInvoiceId = (this.IsUpdate) ? this.Id : 0; //Zero Means No Id Just Save
            stock.PurchaseInvoiceNo = Convert.ToInt32(InvoiceNoMetroTextBox.Text.Trim());
            stock.PurchaseInvoiceDate = PurchaseInvoiceDateMetroDateTime.Value.Date;

            stock.InvoiceNo = Convert.ToInt32(PurchaseInvoiceNoMetroTextBox.Text.Trim());
            stock.InvoiceDate = PurchaseInvoiceDateMetroDateTime.Value.Date;

            stock.PartyId =Convert.ToInt32(PartyNameMetroComboBox.SelectedValue);
            stock.FromCity = Convert.ToInt32(FromCityMetroComboBox.SelectedValue);
            stock.ToCity = Convert.ToInt32(ToCityMetroComboBox.SelectedValue);


            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in PurchaseInvoiceMetroGrid.Rows)
            {   
                stock.ProductName= row.Cells["ProductName"].Value.ToString();
                stock.ProductCode = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["ProductCode"].Value);
                stock.Box = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Box"].Value);
                stock.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value);
                stock.UnitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Price"].Value);
                stock.DiscountInPercent = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["DiscountInPercent"].Value);
                stock.DiscountAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["DiscountAmount"].Value);
                stock.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Amount"].Value);
            }

            stock.SubTotal =Convert.ToDecimal(SubTotalMetroTextBox.Text.Trim());
            stock.DiscountedAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(DiscountedAmountMetroTextBox.Text);
            stock.DiscountPercentage = Convert.ToDecimal(DiscountPercentageMetroTextBox.Text);
            stock.Tax = Convert.ToInt32(TaxMetroTextBox.Text.Trim());
            stock.Freight = Convert.ToInt32(FreightMetroTextBox.Text.Trim());
            stock.NetAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(NetAmountMetroTextBox.Text.Trim());

            stock.AllFreight =Convert.ToDecimal(AllFreightMetroTextBox.Text.Trim());
            stock.AllTax = Convert.ToDecimal(AllTaxMetroTextBox.Text.Trim());

            stock.DriverName = DriverNameMetroTextBox.Text.Trim();
            stock.Mobile = MobileMetroTextBox.Text.Trim();
            stock.Vehicle = VehicleNoMetroTextBox.Text.Trim();
            stock.Remarks = RemarksMetroTextBox.Text.Trim();

            stock.LastUpdatedBy = LoggedInUser.UserName;
            stock.CreatedBy = LoggedInUser.UserName;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        return stock;
    }
```

Comment: Show the error stack trace

Comment: I don't know to trace will you please tell Gabriel Costin.

Comment: Just copy the error message

Comment: In the for each loop he doesn't save all the DataGridview Items.

Comment: It Shows This Error That's not actuall

Comment: Additional information: Procedure or function 'usp_PurchaseInvoiceSaveOrUpdateStockDetails' expects parameter '@DiscounPercentage', which was not supplied.

Comment: Then the parameter `DiscounPercentage` must be null

Comment: I think there must be some kind of typo , just check that you have the same name for `DiscounPercentage` in both cs code and store procedure

Comment: @DiscounPercentage decimal(18,2)

Comment: Yup i have same name in CS and Procedure too.

Comment: But you say in the foreach loop it doesn't save all the items, but that stock details will only have the product of the last product in the datagrid , because you are  indeed looping through products but you are overriding data as far as I can see